# Hiding scrollbar in spinner android

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-dialog

Hi I am working with Spinner widget in Android.

When selecting Spinner the spinner mode set to **dialog**.

In that dialog, I want to avoid

1. Scrollbars
2. White glow (in Lollypop version device) when swiping.

How can I achieve this?
Please share your solutions/ideas.

Comment: Please share what you have done to find a solution

Comment: @codeMagic I have tried with android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none" . In that spinner I set a text view. In that textview i can't use those attributes. I know that overScrollMode have to use in scrollable widgets.